# Способы организации jade?

Tags: сборка, jade, frontend

Для организации css есть SMACSS - «масштабируемая и модульная архитектура для CSS» ,
а что есть подобное для jade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла [данная структура](https://github.com/lime7/sputnik/blob/master/jade.md)

```
templates/                     # Папка с шаблонами Jade
├── blocks/                    # Папка с подключаемыми блоками
├── helpers/                   # Папка с помощниками
│   ├── mixins.jade            # Примеси
│   └── variables.jade         # Переменные
├── layouts/                   # Папка с шаблонами раскладки
│   └── default.jade           # Шаблон раскладки по умолчанию
├── pages/                     # Папка с генерируемыми страницами
│   └── index.jade             # Шаблон одной из страниц
└── partials/                  # Папка с подлючаемыми шаблонами
    ├── footer.jade            # Шаблон подвала
    ├── head.jade              # Шаблон с ресурсами, SEO и мета-тегами
    ├── header.jade            # Шаблон шапки
    └── scripts.jade           # Шаблон со скриптами
```

И то, что получилось у меня для небольшого проекта:

```
views
   |__ partials
   |          |__ _header.jade
   |          |__ _footer.jade
   |__ main.jade
index.jade
```

**index.jade:**

```
extends views/main
...
block title
| Главная страница
```

**main.jade:**

```
...
include partials/_header
...
include partials/_footer
...
```